# Os dados do banco não aparecem na tela, usando angular e php

Tags: html, angularjs

Esse é meu código Angular:

```
<script>
    angular.module("fluxo", ["ngRoute"]);

    angular.module("fluxo").config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/entradas", {
            templateUrl: "views/entradas.html",
            controller: "fluxoCtrl"
        })
        .when("/saidas", {
            templateUrl: "views/saidas.html",
            controller: "fluxoCtrl"
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: "/index"});
    })

    .factory('pegaContas', ['$http', function($http) {
        var _getContas = function(id_empresa) {
            return $http.post("php/index.php", id_empresa);
        };

        return {
            getContas: _getContas
        }
    }])

    .controller("fluxoCtrl", function ($scope, $http, pegaContas) {

        //var id_empresa = {id_empresa: id_empresa};
        var id_empresa = {id_empresa: 1};
        pegaContas.getContas(id_empresa).then(function(data) {
            $scope.mostraTodasContasEntradas = data;
            console.log(data);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Ocorreu um erro: " + error);
        });

    });
</script>
```

E essa é minha página HTML, onde devem aparecer os dados:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Subcategoria</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
                <th>Forma pgto.</th>
                <th>Editar</th>
                <th>Excluir</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="conta in contas">
                <td>{{conta.data}}</td>
                <td>{{conta.categoria}}</td>
                <td>{{conta.subcategoria}}</td>
                <td>{{conta.valor}}</td>
                <td>{{conta.forma_pagamento}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

E sim, já fiz testes e os dados estão vindo do banco.

Retorno do array:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa parte aqui:

```
ng-repeat="conta in contas"
```

A segunda opção deve ser referente ao $scope. No seu caso, seria:

```
$scope.mostraTodasContasEntradas = data.data;
```

Fincado assim:

```
ng-repeat="conta in mostraTodasContasEntradas "
```

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar

Comment: Só apareceu isso na tela "{"id_empresa":1}" heheheh

Comment: Consegue mostrar a sua array?

Comment: Editei o post, está como você sugeriu.

Comment: Array de onde vem os dados? Do php?

Comment: No caso, a array que está sendo atribuida ao "mostraTodasContasEntradas"

Comment: Ta no código que postei acima.

Comment: No caso, esse `console.log(data);` o que ele mostra no console?

Comment: Os dados que vem do banco.

Comment: Você quer que eu coloque aqui, como eles estão vindo?

Comment: Isso, para saber se a array é "legível" para o modo como você está inserindo no html

Comment: 0: Object
categoria: "Rendas Eventuais/Venda Imob."
data: "04/11/2015"
forma_pagamento: "Blablabla"
subcategoria: "Rendas Eventuais/Venda Imob."
valor: "100,00"

Comment: Coloquei um print aqui no post para vc ver o array.

Comment: Editei a resposta, altere o valor do $scope para `$scope.mostraTodasContasEntradas = data.data;`

Comment: Perfeito! Fechou, estão aparecendo...
Mas pq colocar data.data?

Comment: Pelo modo como o PHP retorna. Ele retorna nessa lógica data = array -> objetos. Então basta referenciar o nome da array e depois acessa-la. =D